# How to change color of QWidget in QTableWidget

Tags: qt, colors, paint, qwidget, qslider

I have a QTableWidget. In its cells I need to display 3-state QSliders, that must change their color, depending form their state. -1 = red, 0 - normal, 1 - green. I tried to set QPalette to QSlider - whitout success. I tried to place QSlider into QWidget with Layout and apply palette to QWidget - whitout success.
How to do that? I need any color sign (border or full background, e.t.c) How to do that?

Comment: do you want to show (piece of code) how you have tried? so, we can see what you did.

Comment: This is for label. The background color is sill white.

QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
    QPalette palette = label->palette();
    palette.setColor(label->backgroundRole(), Qt::green);
    label->setText("aaa");
    label->setPalette(palette);
    this->ui->tableWidgetSwitches->setCellWidget(0, 1, label);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QItemDelegate`, then you'll could to rule your `QSlider` into `QTableWidget`.

Detail.

At first, you should derive from `QItemDelegate`. A good docs presents by `doc.qt.digia` [example using qitemdelegate](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.4/itemviews-spinboxdelegate.html)

You should substitute `QSpinBox` to `QSlider`. And after reading this document, you can do needed with setting color your `QSlider`.

```
QTableWidget *table = new QTableWidget(this);
table->setItemDelegateForColumn(index_column, delegate);
// or table->setItemDelegateForRow(index_row, delegate);
// or table->setItemDelegate(delegate);
```

To `editor` was opened always, you should use `openPersistentEditor()`. For example:

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem;
table->insertRow(row);
table->setItem(row, index_your_delegate, item);
table->openPersistentEditor(item);
```

Comment: Can you tell me about this more. Do you know the examples?

Comment: Is this spinBox appears only when cell get focus? I need that they keep their colors without focus, when they not selected.

Comment: Sacha_D, You should sets `openPersistentEditor()` method from QTableWidget.

Comment: Оно красится функцией
item->setBackgroundColor(Qt::green); QPalette к QSlider и к QWidget не работает. Как связать сигнал объекта, создаваемого в QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                           const QModelIndex &index) const; со слотом на форме?

Comment: I created this like example "Using qitemdelegate", but I didn't implement void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const; Also, as all editors are always opened, commit signal never emitting automatcally. In class, that derived from QitemDelegate, I add int rows, columns, that obtained form tableWidget and In the constructor create an array of QPointer<MyEditorWidget> [rows*columns]. Then, in reimplemented function createEditor, I connect slider signal void valueChanged(int) to SLOT, in which I emit commit signal for call reimplemented setModelData function.